# React-Native send multipart/form-data through HTTP

Tags: android, http, react-native

I have a react-native app that needs to send video/images to my server. I already know that normal posts work but when I attempt to send a formData object, it seems to never leave the phone. Here is my code.

```
// method = 'POST';
// body = new formData();
// body contains text data and image/video file
const post = (url, body, token, method) => {
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open(method, url);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer' + token);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7692764ac82');
  xhr.send(body);
  console.log(xhr);
  return xhr.response;
}
```

body is a formData object that contains an image/video.  In the object that xhr prints at the console log the _response contains "Binary FormData part needs a content-type header." But it seems I set it correctly right?

Please help, there are other similar questions but I have run out of ideas.  I have also tried using fetch with no success.

Comment: What do you put in your formData ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The error message is not about the content-type header for the request (which you have set), it's about the content-type header for the *part* (which you did not show, so we have to assume it is missing).

When you add the parts to the `FormData`, don't forget to include a `type`. Example for an image:

```
const body = new FormData();
// ...
body.append('image', {
    uri: 'file:///...',
    type: 'image/jpeg',  // <-  Did you miss that one?
    name: 'someName',
});
```

With the `type` properly set, the React Native runtime should add a `content-type` header for the part. This is done in [`FormData.js` at line 79](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/v0.46.0/Libraries/Network/FormData.js#L79) in v0.46.0 (wherein `value` is the value for your `type` property):

```
if (typeof value.type === 'string') {
    headers['content-type'] = value.type;
}
```

So, when `type` is missing, then `content-type` header for the *part* is missing, and then on Android you end up [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/v0.46.0/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/modules/network/NetworkingModule.java#L508-L515), where you can see the origin of your error message.

This exact error and root cause is discussed in [that GitHub issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7306).

Comment: Really helpful answer!! I was using [ImagePicker](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/#returns-5)  and the type I was passing was 'image', just changed that to 'image/jpeg' and worked perfectly. Thanks!!